# comparing 2 identical strings fails with chai to.equal in protractor

Tags: protractor, chai

I am comparing text from an element with a string. Both are identical and has an apostrophe in it. I am using Protractor in typescript with Chai to.equal
the expect fails.

```
option1=element(by.xpath()); // I'll do it

async getOption1() {
        return await this.Option1.getText();
    }

expect(getOption1()).to.equal("I'll do it");  //fails
```

AssertionError
     + expected - actual

```
 -I'll do it
 +I'll do it
```

It is something to do with the apostrophe i guess, but the below statement passes.

```
expect("I'll do it").to.equal("I'll do it")
```

Can someone please let me know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: `getText()` is  Async API which return a promise. For `chai`, it can't handle promise directly, you can use another package `chai-as-promised` together to handle promise.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a conjecture that in fact may not be equal due to eg. , `\n` or any other symbol. The easiest way to check it is:

```
this.Option1.getText().then((elementText) => {
    console.log('a' + elementText + 'b');
});
```

If it does not print `aI'll do itb` - you get the reason.

Answer (score 1):

`getText()` is Async API which return a promise. `chai` can't handle promise directly, you can use another package [chai-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised) together to handle promise.

```
const chai = require('chai'),
chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'))

global.expect = chai.expect

// if the actual value is a promise, you muse use 'eventually'
// in pattern: expect().to.eventually.xxxx() as following
// otherwise, don't use eventually
expect(getOption1()).to.eventually.equal('I'll do it')

let name = 'tom'
expect(name).to.equal('tom') // don't use eventually at here, 
                             // due to variable: name is not a promise.
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** use [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) to see all invisible characters.

I faced this issue with utf-8 bom, to display all the string characters (also invisible characters) I used [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

```js
console.log({
 string1: encodeURI(string1),
 string2: encodeURI(string2)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which methods are you using to declare your variables, or why, so I would just give it an example with my way. To compare an object with a string, in this case, I would do the following:

```
 var option1 = element(by.xpath()); // I'll do it

 var getOption1 = function() {
      return Option1.getText();
 };

 expect(getOption1()).toBe("I'll do it");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. The string was not equal because one string had “right single quotation mark” instead of the apostrophe.